# System.Exception: 'Error loading msvcr120.dll (ErrorCode: 193)'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

my system is windows 64 bit.

my projects runs on visual studio 2022. C#, .NET Framework 4.8 MVC.

when I try to run the program, I get this error:

```
System.Exception: 'Error loading msvcr120.dll (ErrorCode: 193)'
```

[image]

I read all kinds of documents I found about this error, talking about a 32 bit system/program that is not compatible with running on 64-bit operating system.

This is strange, because I have another computer where this error is not received, also 64-bit, and I copied the dll file from it.
(the project is exact same project).
I set the file as shown:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this error?

Comment: Is your exe compiled for 32-bits or 64-bits? And which msvcr120.dll does it try to load then? The  x64 or the x86 one?

Comment: @rene it should be 64-bit. I'm not sure how to verify that

Answer (score 1):

For now the problem is solved, in a very strange way!

I tried to update the Microsodt.SqlServer.Types package on the Nuget to the last version - and I get an error from the code.
so I downgrade the version, and now the error no longer appear.

if it help anyone in the future - the update version I currently have is:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Types: 14.0.1016.290